# Is a merge commit always going to be identical to a squashed commit?

Tags: git

Let's say a git repo's `main` branch looks like this:

```
A --> B
```

A feature branch is created from the head of that main branch, and then two commits are added:

```
A --> B
       \
        C --> D
```

If we were to squash and merge the feature branch into the main branch with rebasing, `main` would look like this:

```
A --> B --> E
```

(with `E` being the squashed commit of `C` and `D`)

If we instead merge the feature branch into `main` using a merge commit, it would look like this:

```
A --> B   - -  (m)
       \       /
        C --> D
```

**Can we conclude that the diff of the merge commit `(m)` is always going to be identical to the squashed commit `E`?**

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the diff of the merge commit"? You're just talking about the state of the tracked files, correct?

Comment: As a plumbing sidenote that may help with your understanding, do note commits don't contain "diffs". Each commit references exactly one _tree object_, which represents an exact state of the working tree. You can view which tree a commit references with `git cat-file commit <rev>`. Any number of commits can reference the same tree. And like everything in git, trees are content-indexed, meaning that the content of a tree uniquely identifies its object name. So, you can check whether two commits have the same "diff" by running `git cat-file ` on them and seeing if they reference the same tree.

Comment: If we exclude git conflicts that with some error could be solved differently (but here in the exact scenario you describe, no other commit could introduce conflicts...), yes, the squash commit E and the result of the merge commit (m) contains exactly the same changes compared to commit B (so the code in the working directory will be exactly the same in the 2 situations)

Comment: @Brian61354270 "You're just talking about the state of the tracked files, correct?" yes, because otherwise calling them identical commits is somewhat nonsensical, because they would have a different SHA and are a fundamentally different kind of commit

Comment: @mdhuke “yes, because otherwise calling them identical commits is somewhat nonsensical”—You can say that the trees are identical: `<commit>^{tree}`. A commit points to a tree. If two commits have identical content (but may have different commit message and things like that) they will point to the same tree.